# How to using electronjs app to sign in into Cloudkit database automatically without sign in?

Tags: electron, cloudkit

My electron app want to access to cloudkit database with the same apple id inside macbook.
But In cloudkitjs we dont have any option for get signed in directly.
Thanks!

Any library or functions can help to resolve my problem?